# find_if() returns unexpected iterator type in const function

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, type-conversion, constants

The following is a distilled version of some code that produces the following error with g++ 4.8:

```
x.cpp: In member function ‘void Container::find() const’:
x.cpp:11:71: error: 
conversion from ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const Element*, std::vector<Element> >’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<Element>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Element*, std::vector<Element> >}’ requested vector<Element>::iterator it = find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), f);
```

And here is the code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Element{};
struct Functor{ bool operator()(const Element & ){return false;}; };
struct Container{
   vector<Element> v;
   void find() const {
      Functor f;
      vector<Element>::iterator it = find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), f);
   }
};
int main() { return 0; }
```

The error disappears after removing the const qualifier on the `find()` function.
What is the reason for the error? References to standard are encouraged.
The logic of the predicate etc. have been removed to focus on the problem of interest.
clang 3.4 produces similar results.

Comment: `return 0` in `main` is implied.

Comment: If you have C++11 use auto for the returned variable.

Answer (score 2):

Since `v` is `const` in `Container::find` (which is itself `const`), the type of `v.begin()` and `v.end()`, and thus the return type of `find_if`, is `vector<Element>::const_iterator`.

Comment: So is it the case that all variables defined within a const-qualified function are silently declared as const even if their definitions don't have the const qualifier?

Comment: @user2141130: Sort of. That's how member functions work. (The members aren't "redeclared". Rather, the values to which the member names refer are `const` values, generally.)